# What does cat' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The man sitting in the iron seat did not look like a man; gloved,
>   goggled, rubber dust mask over nose and mouth, he was a part of the
>   monster, a robot in the seat. The thunder of the cylinders sounded
>   through the country, became one with the air and the earth, so that
>   earth and air muttered in sympathetic vibration. The driver could not
>   control it-straight across country it went, cutting through a dozen
>   farms and straight back. A twitch at the controls could swerve the
>   **cat'**, but the driver's hands could not twitch because the monster that built the tractors, the monster that sent the tractor out, had
>   somehow got into the driver's hands, into his brain and muscle, had
>   goggled him and muzzled him-goggled his mind, muzzled his speech,
>   goggled his perception, muzzled his protest. 
> (John Steinbeck, The
>   Grapes of Wrath)

What is ***cat’***? Is it displaying a certain pronunciation for *cat* or does it mean something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It refers to the tractor:

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cat):

> 6) cat - a large tracked vehicle that is propelled by two endless metal belts; frequently used for moving earth in construction and farm work

The most famous tractor company in the world is Caterpillar Tractor, known as "cat" for short, which is why the term is sometimes used to mean "tractor."

Comment: Thank you I get the meaning. And one another question, actually in the original question: what does cat' (with apostrophe) mean? (* Oh, your name has Cat!)

Comment: @Listenever The word derives from the brand/manufacturer [***Caterpillar***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_Inc.#Origins), whose founder invented the tracked tractor; Steinbeck may employ the apostrophe to indicate it's a contraction.

Comment: @Listenever :")) Yeah! I am a Persian! Honestly I only could find this and surely StoneyB as a guru can complete my answer and correct it if needed.

Comment: @PersianCat I’ve got what I needed wholly from your answer to Mr. StoneyB’s adding. Yes, He is really a guru. Thank you, you all.

Comment: @Listenever You are welcome! I learned a lot from your questions. ;)